# Substituir o texto de uma textbox quando o utilizador faz um novo input na mesma textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

Eu tenho uma `textbox` onde, através de uma outra página lhe passo um e-mail.

```
txtemail.text = "email@sapo.pt"
```

E quando a minha página faz o `load`, naquela `textbox` aparece: `email@sapo.pt`.

Só que se eu tentar fazer um novo `input` naquela `textbox` ele não guarda, ficando sempre com o `email@sapo.pt`.

Tenho o `AutoPostBack="true"`, já tentei também `OnTextChanged` mas não consegui.

Precisava alguma coisa do gênero.

```
txtemail.text = txtemail.text.newInput()
```

Esta é a minha textbox

```
<div class="form-group">
<asp:Label ID="LEmailP" runat="server" Text="Para :" Font-Size="Medium" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox CssClass="labelEmail" ID="txtEmailP" required="true" MaxLength="50" runat="server" type="text" TabIndex="2" AutoPostBack="true" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$" title="ex: sapo@sapo.pt" placeholder="Titular Email"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

Passo o meu email por página aqui ( ponho no page load )

`string email = Request.QueryString["email"];
  txtEmailP.Text = email;`

Comment: Poste toda a parte relevante do código

Comment: @LeandroAngelo se eu tentar alterar o valor da minha `txtEmailP` na página onde me encontro, como tenho o `AutoPostBack="true"` ela automaticamente me mudar para o email que eu passei por link`Request.QueryString["email"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom você não colocou o seu código, mas tendo em vista o comportamento, é possível afirmar que você está atribuindo o valor passado na `QueryString` para o seu input `txtEmail` no evento de `Page_Load()`. E como atribuiu o comportamento de `AutoPostBack="True"` para ele ou qualquer outro componente na tela. Toda vez que esse recurso for ativado você vai passar pelo `Page_Load()`novamente e receberá o valor que está informado na `QueryString`.

A solução é simples, adicione a condição para que essa atribuição só ocorra quando o carregamento da página não for proveniente de um `PostBack`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        txtEmail.Text = Request.QueryString["email"];
    }

}
```

Comment: Tem toda a razão ! Funcionou perfeitamente um abraço